# conduction-diffusion heat 2D model with non constant capacity

Tags: python, fipy

I've spent quite some time on developing a two-dimensional heat conduction-diffusion model for steady state approximation.

[image: PDE]

For simplicity consider a laminar shear film, i.e. zero velocity at the bottom and a constant velocity increase.

[image: shear]

Heat capacity might either be constant or linear increasing over temperature.

Boundary conditions are a constant inlet temperature (left) and constant input flux (top) while all exterior faces are forced to have no gradient.

See the code [here](https://gist.github.com/derDavidT/ea2bf73bae3c0e5152d2).

When using a constant heat capacity input power is equal to output power.

```
input = 50.00e3 W
ouput = 50.00e3 W
```

When using a non-constant heat capacity they differ significantly. The more heat capacity varies over temperature, the more input and output differ.

```
input = 50.00e3 W
ouput = 33.78e3 W
```

Introducing a variable velocity coefficient (here v * c * rho) was done as stated in the fipy FAQ (which only explicitly shows an example for diffusion terms). Grid resolution does not change output power. So I'd say it is not a grid-problem. I've also tried adding a transient term and solving for a very high time step, which does not change the solution.

I fear I've done something terribly wrong when defining the convection term, but cannot find the error. Also I'm confused if fipy is able to mix `theta` (a rank=0 cell variable) with the `velocity` (a rank=1 cell variable) and then cast them into a face variable, which is necessary for the convection term.

Comment: I just did the same for a constant velocity (no shear). And the problem is still the same.

Comment: and what's the question exactly?

Comment: Why is the model not working as expected, i.e. why do input and output differ? I am very sure that (a) my calculation of the input and output are correct (b) I use fipy according to my understangin of the FAQ and examples. Yet, the model does not calculate correctly with a solution dependent velocity coefficient. I suspect fipy to have some kind of bug, and I'd like to either have this debunked or confirmed.

Comment: It looks like you're calculating output power as $\rho \int_\text{bottom}^\text{top} \int_{\vartheta_L}^{\vartheta_R} c_p(\vartheta) v(y)\,d\vartheta\,dy$, is that right? Forgive my ignorance, but can you explain why? If I understand mathematically what you want to calculate, I can better formulate a solution in FiPy.

Comment: Seems good. What we have is a known inlet enthalpy (left faces) and a known input flux (top faces). Thus, the output enthalpy (right faces) should be the sum of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the divergence theorem

[image: divergence theorem]

I would calculate the surface flux with

```
Cp = mymodel.fluid.capacity(solution, use_constant_cp)
veloc = fipy.CellVariable(mesh=mesh, value=0., rank=1, name='velocity')
veloc[0] = mymodel.shear * mesh.y
R = ((Cp * solution * veloc).faceValue.dot(mesh._orientedAreaProjections) * mesh.facesRight * mymodel.fluid.rho).sum()
L = ((Cp * solution * veloc).faceValue.dot(mesh._orientedAreaProjections) * mesh.facesLeft * mymodel.fluid.rho).sum()
print "{:.3e} J/s received.".format((R+L).value)
```

I get `4.958e+04 J/s received.` The answer improves with x resolution.

Note that because this uses the velocity vector, `L` is the flux in and `R` is the flux out and so we add them to get the difference. The `_orientedAreaProjections` vector points into the domain for all exterior faces, so the dot product is positive when the flux enters the domain and negative when it exits. Because we're integrating over the entire exterior boundary, you could just write

```
J_dot_n = ((Cp * solution * veloc).faceValue.dot(mesh._orientedAreaProjections) * (mesh.facesLeft + mesh.facesRight) * mymodel.fluid.rho).sum()
print "{:.3e} J/s received.".format(J_dot_n.value)
```

Similarly, I would calculate the input heat flux with `(mymodel.flux * mesh._faceAreas * mesh.facesTop).sum()`.

What you've calculated, I think, is

[image]

If you want to calculate the volume integral form of the divergence theorem, you can do that, but it would be

```
velocF = fipy.FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, value=0., rank=1, name='velocity')
velocF[0] = mymodel.shear * mesh.faceCenters[1]
((Cp * solution).faceValue * velocF * mymodel.fluid.rho).divergence.cellVolumeAverage * mesh.cellVolumes.sum()
```

`_faceAreas` and `_orientedAreaProjections` come up often enough that we should make them part of the public API.

[Edited for clarity to address questions that came up in the comments]

Comment: Just by looking at your solution I have a small question: Why add(!) up `R` and `L`. Does `_orientedAreaProjections` yield a negative value for `L` (or vice versa for `R`)? I will have a closer look at it today. PS: Sorry for my delay.

Comment: Works as you described... However I'd like to know what my mistake in calculating the enthalpy increase is.

Comment: The flux is into the domain on the left and out of the domain on the right. `_orientedAreaProjects` is the product of the face area and the oriented normal vector. By dotting with that vector there is a sign difference between left and right that amounts to adding the values.

Comment: It's sort of a fluke that your approach worked for the constant heat capacity case. In 1D (and you basically stacked up a bunch of 1D solutions for each height), the net convective heat flux is `cp * rho * v * (T_R - T_L)` and *for constant cp*, your `sci.integrate.quad(mymodel.fluid.capacity, theta_lo[k], theta_hi[k],...` yields the same value. For non-constant, cp, though, the net heat flux is unchanged, but the integral will include a (1/2)T**2 term.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that, by the divergence theorem, $\int_S \vec{J}\cdot\hat{n}\,dS = \int_V \nabla\cdot\vec{J}\,dV$. What I calculated is essentially the surface integral form. What you've calculated, I think, is $\int_V |\vec{J}|\,dV$. If you want to calculate the volume integral, you can do that, but it would be ` ((Cp * solution).faceValue * velocF * mymodel.fluid.rho).divergence.cellVolumeAverage * mesh.cellVolumes.sum()`, where `velocF = fipy.FaceVariable(mesh=mesh, value=0., rank=1, name='velocity')` and defined with `mesh.faceCenters[1]`.